Node.js function partially completing even with Async/Await implemented
I cannot for the life of me wrap my head around what I am doing wrong with this Async/Await concept. Here is my Node.js code below (two separate files).
So, the console.log("hasInvoiceAlreadyBeenPaid:", hasInvoiceAlreadyBeenPaid); line runs before the controller.checkIfAuthNetChargedInvoice() has been completed and shows that hasInvoiceAlreadyBeenPaid has a value of undefined.
What am I doing wrong with this code? It's an Async function and I am using Await, so am super confused wrapping my head around this. I should mention that the checkIfAuthNetChargedInvoice function runs successfully but right after the console.log(" ~ ctrl:", ctrl); line shows in the logs, the console.log: hasInvoiceAlreadyBeenPaid: undefined; appears in the logs right after that. Then the remainder of checkIfAuthNetChargedInvoiceruns successfully. I know this is just a misunderstanding of async/await but what the heck am I doing wrong?
execute.js
const controller = require("./controller");
const hasInvoiceAlreadyBeenPaid = await controller.checkIfAuthNetChargedInvoice(
  lastUnpaidSubscriptionInvoice,
  authorizeNetProfileId,
);
console.log("hasInvoiceAlreadyBeenPaid:", hasInvoiceAlreadyBeenPaid);
if (hasInvoiceAlreadyBeenPaid) {
  console.log(" INVOICE ALREADY PAID! ");
}
--

controller.js
exports.checkIfAuthNetChargedInvoice = async (invoice, customerProfileId) => {
  try {
    const invoiceString = invoice._id.toString();
    const authNetInvoiceNumber = invoiceString.slice(-12);

    var merchantAuthenticationType =
      new ApiContracts.MerchantAuthenticationType();
    merchantAuthenticationType.setName(authorizeNetAPILoginKey);
    merchantAuthenticationType.setTransactionKey(authorizeNetTransactionKey);

    var paging = new ApiContracts.Paging();
    paging.setLimit(100);
    paging.setOffset(1);

    var sorting = new ApiContracts.TransactionListSorting();
    sorting.setOrderBy(ApiContracts.TransactionListOrderFieldEnum.ID);
    sorting.setOrderDescending(true);

    var getRequest = new ApiContracts.GetTransactionListForCustomerRequest();
    getRequest.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthenticationType);
    getRequest.setCustomerProfileId(customerProfileId);
    getRequest.setPaging(paging);
    getRequest.setSorting(sorting);

    var ctrl = new ApiControllers.GetTransactionListForCustomerController(
      getRequest.getJSON(),
    );
    console.log(" ~ ctrl:", ctrl);

    ctrl.execute(async function () {
      var apiResponse = ctrl.getResponse();
      console.log(" ~ apiResponse:", apiResponse);

      var response = new ApiContracts.GetTransactionListResponse(apiResponse);

      console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));

      if (response != null) {
        if (
          response.getMessages().getResultCode() ==
          ApiContracts.MessageTypeEnum.OK
        ) {
          console.log(
            "Message Code : " +
              response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getCode(),
          );
          console.log(
            "Message Text : " +
              response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getText(),
          );
          if (response.getTransactions() != null) {
            var transactions = response.getTransactions().getTransaction();
            for (var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
              const transaction = transactions[i];
              const transactionId = transaction.getTransId();
              const transactionStatus = transaction.getTransactionStatus();
              const settleAmount = transaction.getSettleAmount();

              if (
                transaction.invoiceNumber == authNetInvoiceNumber &&
                transactionStatus === "settledSuccessfully"
              ) {
                invoice.status = "paid";
                await invoice.save();
                return true;
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          const newErrorLog = new ErrorLog({ error });
          await newErrorLog.save();
        }
      } else {
        let errorText = "checkIfAuthNetChargedInvoice: Null Response ";
        if (invoice._id) {
          errorText =
            "checkIfAuthNetChargedInvoice: Null Response for Invoice: " +
            invoice._id;
        }
        const newErrorLog = new ErrorLog({ error: errorText });
        await newErrorLog.save();
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    const newErrorLog = new ErrorLog({ error });
    await newErrorLog.save();
  }
};


global await works only in ES module

probably need to wrap ctrl.execute( ()=> {....}) in a promise, I am assuming the function provided to ctrl.execute runs after the response is received (like a callback). The function checkIfAuthNetChargedInvoice  would return void  after running the line ctrl.execute(callback) since there is nothing to wait for after that line

try updating the function where you return promise
exports.checkIfAuthNetChargedInvoice = async (invoice, customerProfileId) => {
    try {
      const invoiceString = invoice._id.toString();
      const authNetInvoiceNumber = invoiceString.slice(-12);
  
      var merchantAuthenticationType =
        new ApiContracts.MerchantAuthenticationType();
      merchantAuthenticationType.setName(authorizeNetAPILoginKey);
      merchantAuthenticationType.setTransactionKey(authorizeNetTransactionKey);
  
      var paging = new ApiContracts.Paging();
      paging.setLimit(100);
      paging.setOffset(1);
  
      var sorting = new ApiContracts.TransactionListSorting();
      sorting.setOrderBy(ApiContracts.TransactionListOrderFieldEnum.ID);
      sorting.setOrderDescending(true);
  
      var getRequest = new ApiContracts.GetTransactionListForCustomerRequest();
      getRequest.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthenticationType);
      getRequest.setCustomerProfileId(customerProfileId);
      getRequest.setPaging(paging);
      getRequest.setSorting(sorting);
  
      var ctrl = new ApiControllers.GetTransactionListForCustomerController(
        getRequest.getJSON(),
      );
      console.log(" ~ ctrl:", ctrl);
  
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ctrl.execute(async function () {
            var apiResponse = ctrl.getResponse();
            console.log(" ~ apiResponse:", apiResponse);
      
            var response = new ApiContracts.GetTransactionListResponse(apiResponse);
      
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
      
            if (response != null) {
              if (
                response.getMessages().getResultCode() ==
                ApiContracts.MessageTypeEnum.OK
              ) {
                console.log(
                  "Message Code : " +
                    response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getCode(),
                );
                console.log(
                  "Message Text : " +
                    response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getText(),
                );
                if (response.getTransactions() != null) {
                  var transactions = response.getTransactions().getTransaction();
                  for (var i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
                    const transaction = transactions[i];
                    const transactionId = transaction.getTransId();
                    const transactionStatus = transaction.getTransactionStatus();
                    const settleAmount = transaction.getSettleAmount();
      
                    if (
                      transaction.invoiceNumber == authNetInvoiceNumber &&
                      transactionStatus === "settledSuccessfully"
                    ) {
                      invoice.status = "paid";
                      await invoice.save();
                      resolve(true);
                    }
                  }
                }
              } else {
                const newErrorLog = new ErrorLog({ error });
                await newErrorLog.save();
                resolve(false)

              }
            } else {
              let errorText = "checkIfAuthNetChargedInvoice: Null Response ";
              if (invoice._id) {
                errorText =
                  "checkIfAuthNetChargedInvoice: Null Response for Invoice: " +
                  invoice._id;
              }
              const newErrorLog = new ErrorLog({ error: errorText });
              await newErrorLog.save();
              resolve(false)
            }
          });
     })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      const newErrorLog = new ErrorLog({ error });
      await newErrorLog.save();
    }
  };


Global await only works in ES module so you can wrap it in a async function then call it.
  const controller = require("./controller");

  async function checkInvoicePaid() {
    const hasInvoiceAlreadyBeenPaid = await controller.checkIfAuthNetChargedInvoice(
      lastUnpaidSubscriptionInvoice,
      authorizeNetProfileId,
    );
    console.log("hasInvoiceAlreadyBeenPaid:", hasInvoiceAlreadyBeenPaid);
    if (hasInvoiceAlreadyBeenPaid) {
      console.log(" INVOICE ALREADY PAID! ");
    }
  }
  
  checkInvoicePaid();

